# Httparty get information to use inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

So i have this at the moment.

```
api = HTTParty.get("api url here").parsed_response
@api = api["Events"]
```

This is returning this.

```
[{"Id"=>1015765, "Date"=>"/Date(1468062000000+0100)/", "VenueName"=>"Milton Keynes Bowl", "Town"=>"Milton Keynes", "Country"=>"UK", "LayoutId"=>3932, "EventGroupId"=>32347, "VenueId"=>3596}]
```

now how do i go about getting the `VenueName` into the view?

I've tried just putting `<%= @api.Id %>` However that didn't work

I am also wondering if it'd be better get the venue name in the controller then it can be used elsewhere?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Since @api is an array of Hashes, you can do something like this in your view:

```
<% @api.each do |event| %>
  <%= event['VenueName'] %>
<% end %>
```

For each of the events in the array, it will output the VenueName element from the Hash.

To get the first event's name in the controller:

```
@name = @api.first['VenueName']
```

Comment: Hey, How can i use this in my controller?

Thanks,